# .htaccess Rewrite - change visible URL AND send it to a certain file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have searched around but can't find the answer to this relatively simple question; 
how change the visible URL, AND send it to a certain file.

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^xyz/([A-Za-z0-9\ -]+)$ index.php?xyz=$1 [L]
```

Links are built like mydomain.com/xyz/uniquecode

Above Rewriterule triggers the file index.php?xyz=uniquecode

But I ALSO want it to change the **visible** URL to mydomain.com or maybe mydomain.com/someotherfolder

How do I do it? 
I think I have to create some rewrite conditions but not sure how. 
Thanks in advance.

....................................................................................................

**EDIT :**

Just to clarify:
What I want is to give out personal links like

**mydomain.com/affiliate/users-unique-code-here** and when the link is clicked the url in the browser instead show

**mydomain.com** or

**mydomain.com/somefolder**

while it of course trigger my file index.php?affiliate=users-unique-code-here

It should be possible to do all this in the .htaccess

Comment: Was this really such a hard question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes `start_session(); if (isset($_GET['xyz'])){$_SESSION['topost']=$_GET;header('location: mydomain.com');} if (isset($_SESSION['topost'])){$_GET=$_SESSION['topost'];unset($_SESSION['topost']‌​);}`
if isset $_GET save it and set location, at the new location if exists saved data, set it to the $_GET and new visible address but $_GET is the same

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand you, this will help you.

Before header put a piece of code like this:

`<?php
if (isset($_GET['xyz'])){header('location: /xyz/'+$_GET['xyz'])} ?>`

This will turn `mydomain.com/index.php?xyz=code` to `mydomain.com/xyz/code`.

Comment: Bah, every time I hit enter it creates a new comment :)
What I meant is what I want is to give out personal links like 
http://mydomain.com/affiliate/users-unique-code-here and when the link is clicked the url in the browser instead show 
http://mydomain.com or
http://mydomain.com/somefolder
while it of course trigger my file index.php?affiliate=users-unique-code-here

It should be possible to do all this in the .htaccess

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(*.)/(*.) index.php?$1=$2 [L]`

Comment: if you want to see `mydomain.com` you will have to post back(to `$_POST`) every `$_GET` data to the `index.php`

Comment: Can't I set up a RewriteCondition for this?

Comment: With rewritecondition you can't send post data. Only get, as i wrote.

Comment: So the way to go is to send mydomain.com/xyz/1234 to mydomain.com/index.php?xyz=1234 and in the php file catch xyz, save it in a session and send user to a new header('Location: mydomain.com') ?
Then in reloaded mydomain.com pick up the session and do whatever with it?

Comment: yes `start_session(); if (isset($_GET['xyz'])){$_SESSION['topost']=$_GET;header('location: mydomain.com');} if (isset($_SESSION['topost'])){$_GET=$_SESSION['topost'];unset($_SESSION['topost']);}`  if isset $_GET save it and set location, at the new location if exists saved data, set it to the `$_GET` and new visible address but `$_GET` is the same

Comment: If you put it as an answer instead of comment I can give you credit.